# How can I verify a signed message?

Tags: message-signing, message-verification

I can send a signed message using the standard client, but if I see a signed message in, say, a forum, how can I verify it?

I understand this hasn't yet been implemented in the GUI for the standard client.

Comment: Shifted my answer from this question  http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4131/516 because the question was changed to ask for pseudocode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this bitcointalk thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=70911.0), it can be done via the [JSON-RPC](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29) API:
Code:

```
verifymessage [address] [signature] [message]
```

This feature has also been included in the GUI of the [Armory](http://bitcoinarmory.com/) client:

> To Verify a Signature Block with Armory (works fine in offline mode):
>
> ```
> Open Armory, go to the menu, "Tools"-->"Message Signing"
> Click on "Import Signature Block" at the bottom of the screen.
> Paste the signature block, and click "Okay"
> Address will be checked against public key, public key checked against signature for the given message
> ```
>
> None of this requires the blockchain, so if you are on a system that
>   couldn't normally run Armory, you only need to run with the
>   "--noblockchain" option.  This allows you to verify Armory signature
>   blocks without even having an Armory wallet!  If you're intrigued, try
>   this one:  (get Armory if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it online. For example here:

https://brainwallet.github.io/#verify

Comment: brainwallet seems to be dead